# Why does kubectl have different behavior with sudo?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Running `kubectl get pods` with sudo:

```
sudo kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Running as a normal user:

```
kubectl get pods
No resources found.
```

Comment: run it with like this `kubectl --kubeconfig=/home/admin/.kube/config`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, kubectl looks in ~/.kube/config (or the file pointed to be $KUBECONFIG) to determine what server to connect to. Your home directory and environment are different when running commands as root. When no connection info is found, kubectl defaults to localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

- When you run `sudo kubectl`, kubectl will refer to /root/.kube/config .
- When you run `kubectl` without sudo, kubectl will refer to $HOME/.kube/config .
- If the `<user home dir>/.kube/config` file is not found by the kubectl, it will just call the default kubernetes API server URL localhost:8080 .

Answer (score -1):

You would have run these commands from the normal user :

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf
export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf
```

which would have copied config file in your normal user home directory and that is why you are able to get to the connection from the normal host and not from sudo.

Comment: Where does `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` come from?

Comment: It's kubernetes default directory.

Comment: Maybe directly on the master node, but not on any client. Also the location might differ on custom Kubernetes nodes (eg our cluster doesn't know that location).