# How to get the kubernetes config via sudo when using gcloud?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Previously I asked a question: [Why does kubectl have different behavior with sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536428/why-does-kubectl-have-different-behavior-with-sudo)

So it turns out that using `gcloud`, `kubectl` config is generated somehow. However when / how is this generated? And how could I generate the config to be present for the root user as well (for sudo purposes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type `gcloud container clusters get-credentials <clustername> --zone <zone>` then gcloud puts some credentials for the specified cluster into your `~/.kube/config` file, and makes it the active context in kubectl.    The gcloud command is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials).

If you want the root user on your local machine to be able to access the cluster too, you need to install kubectl and gcloud where the root user can see them, and repeat the`get-credentials` command.